# Monitor log files in realtime, like "top" monitors processes [OS X]

Tags: mac-osx, logging, log-files, realtime

Is there a command/program for OS X that allows me to hook to a file and display its changes in realtime without re-opening it, much like "top" monitors system processes in realtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `tail` to monitor single log file.

If file is deleted, then created again you may want to use `tail -F` to actively monitor file changes

If same file is being appended too use `tail -f` to actively monitor file changes

Comment: It doesn't seem to display changes as the file updates

Comment: It does, at least on FreeBSD and linuxes. Should work on Mac OS X too.

Comment: @Mark how do you modify the file during checking?

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that the file is in a Dropbox and is updated perhaps a bit differently?

Comment: It does work on OS X. On my systems anyway.

Comment: Try `tail -F`. Consult with `man tail` for more details about these options.

Comment: It also works on a Dropbox folder.

Comment: -F instead of -f did it, thank you!

Comment: `multitail` can monitor multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative may be doing `less the-interesting-file` and hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Or `less +F logfile`

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this on file sync'd by dropbox the chances are it is creating a new file with a different inode so the tail -f command and the less +F command do not work since they are still referencing the old file handle they opened initially.

I suggest trying

```
watch "tail /path/to/filename"
```

It feels hackish but at least every X seconds it will re run tail on the filename giving you the updated output regardless of whether or not the inodes change on the file.